# Why is Next.js 13.4.2 app showing html chunks on the browser if left for a period of time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, next.js, vercel

I'm using app router from Next.js 13.4.2 on my app. On its initial load, the app opens the way it should and everything works fine but I noticed that after the app sits long enough, or switch tab to a different tab. When I go back to the tab I opened the website on. It shows chunks of html code on the browser. The website is currently hosted on AWS amplify.

This is what is showing on the page after I leave the page for some minutes.

```
1:HL["/_next/static/media/7777133e901cd5ed-s.p.woff2",{"as":"font","type":"font/woff2"}] 
2:HL["/_next/static/media/916d3686010a8de2-s.p.woff2",{"as":"font","type":"font/woff2"}] 
3:HL["/_next/static/media/9a881e2ac07d406b-s.p.woff2",{"as":"font","type":"font/woff2"}] 
4:HL["/_next/static/media/bd427f25ac24d036-s.p.woff2",{"as":"font","type":"font/woff2"}] 
5:HL["/_next/static/media/d36a2a2bb416f59e-s.p.woff2",{"as":"font","type":"font/woff2"}] 
6:HL["/_next/static/css/2a07d734a20a99b3.css",{"as":"style"}]
7:HL["/_next/static/css/ecd948767e096f78.css",{"as":"style"}] 

0:[[
    ["",{"children":["__PAGE__",{}]},"$undefined","$undefined",true],
    "$L8",[[["$","link","0",{"rel":"stylesheet","href":"/_next/static/css/2a07d734a20a99b3.css","precedence":"next"}],["$","link","1",{"rel":"stylesheet","href":"/_next/static/css/ecd948767e096f78.css","precedence":"next"}]],["$L9",["$","meta",null,{"name":"next-size-adjust"}]]]
]] 
a:HL["/_next/static/css/458cf75f1ee9813b.css",{"as":"style"}] 
b:I{"id":"5227","chunks":["201:static/chunks/201-b763b97b8d16f706.js","185:static/chunks/app/layout-350020619d648b75.js"],"name":"","async":false} 
c:I{"id":"9544","chunks":["272:static/chunks/webpack-eccc90b774de8c50.js","667:static/chunks/2443530c-942d23a6246cf16c.js","139:static/chunks/139-b08bf36040abf8bb.js"],"name":"","async":false} 
d:I{"id":"99","chunks":["272:static/chunks/webpack-eccc90b774de8c50.js","667:static/chunks/2443530c-942d23a6246cf16c.js","139:static/chunks/139-b08bf36040abf8bb.js"],"name":"","async":false}
e:I{"id":"9288","chunks":["776:static/chunks/b7d461da-c24d426981069a69.js","358:static/chunks/ae573a17-86c3c0dbf6820279.js","11:static/chunks/11-ada55797f12a86c7.js","414:static/chunks/414-737d93b2fc27a9fe.js","553:static/chunks/553-0c921218202d70d5.js","798:static/chunks/app/privacy/layout-f55345026eeff814.js"],"name":"","async":false} 
f:I{"id":"2011","chunks":["821:static/chunks/1418c200-705f4a11b96a8412.js","739:static/chunks/543ac898-9e7c2265ce202fd3.js","11:static/chunks/11-ada55797f12a86c7.js","348:static/chunks/348-e537d997b144ed0c.js","201:static/chunks/201-b763b97b8d16f706.js","549:static/chunks/549-0ee789f6816fec15.js","384:static/chunks/384-e052fd0b08e9ac2f.js","857:static/chunks/app/events/[id]/page-234115e5ba29cda9.js"],"name":"","async":f ...
```

I tried deploying the same app on vercel and it works very well there.

I feel it might be a caching issue in aws. Please how do I solve it.

Comment: "It shows chunks of html code on the browser" – what chunks, what's the content? That's the important part here.

Comment: I have edited the post to show the kind of chunks I am seeing on the page

Comment: I've also used AWS Amplify to deploy Next.js v13.4.4 app. I'm still facing exactly the same issue here. Anyone got a clue to solve the problem?

Comment: I have the same issue. Nextjs 13.4.2

Comment: If you guys are still having an issue, you could try this - Up your nextjs version to 13.4.7. This solved. This update actually attaches a uid/timestamp to the pages

Comment: It's still reproducible even on 13.5.6